# Modbus TCP socket class no replied from Moxa

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, modbus

ok here is my TCP connection code :

```
        //sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, 1234));

        try
        {
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP_AddressTXT.Text), Convert.ToInt16(IP_PortTXT.Text));
            sck.Connect(localEndPoint);
            //sck.h
        }
        catch( Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to remote end point! ", e.Message);
            return;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Connected to : " + IP_AddressTXT.Text);
        Enter1.Text = "connected...";  }
```

so that part works .. it connects...

here is my send code :

```
public void Send( byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, int timeout)
    {
        int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
        int sent = 0;  // how many bytes is already sent

            try
            {
                sent = sck.Send(buffer);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error", ex.Message); // any serious error //occurr
            }
    }
```

I used WireShark and it says I am sending this :

```
0000   00 90 e8 30 f8 e0 34 e6 d7 15 0d d5 08 00 45 00  ...0..4.......E.
0010   00 30 3c a3 40 00 80 06 60 fa a9 fe 08 2d a9 fe  .0<.@...`....-..
0020   01 01 fe 20 10 a4 a6 74 fa 75 17 c7 ca e0 50 18  ... ...t.u....P.
0030   40 29 17 9a 00 00 01 03 01 a6 00 01 65 d5        @)..........e.
```

The 01 03 a6 00 01 65 d5 is my modbus message.

now I do see a replied on Wireshark from the Moxa it is :

```
0000   34 e6 d7 15 0d d5 00 90 e8 30 f8 e0 08 00 45 00  4........0....E.
0010   00 28 16 ec 40 00 80 06 86 b9 a9 fe 01 01 a9 fe  .(..@...........
0020   08 2d 10 a4 fe 85 09 13 68 d7 c4 1c 89 ee 50 10  .-......h.....P.
0030   83 24 00 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00              .$.f........
```

but when I go to read that message and when I call the function Receive the program just sits there and does not do anything

here is my read function :

```
public void Receive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, int timeout)
    {
        int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
        int received = 0;  // how many bytes is already received
        //sck.Listen(100);
            try
            {

                received = sck.Receive(buffer);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error", ex.Message);
            }
        processingData(buffer);
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?
why does it just sit at received = sck.Receive(buffer); and never does anything ?

Comment: is that 65 d5 at the end of your request the CRC?

Comment: Ok, that's weird, you're not supposed to send the CRC in Modbus TCP. It seems you're trying to read some holding registers. Can you tell me their addresses?

Comment: What type is sck exactly? Why are you using the socket directly instead of TcpClient?

Comment: sck is a socket object @ Tobias Knauss

Comment: I did not know about TcpClient. Is there an example ?

Comment: Ronaldo you were right!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a Modbus RTU PDU over a Modbus TCP connection, that will not work.
You need to build a Modbus TCP PDU with the MBAP header. You can check the details here:

http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Messaging_Implementation_Guide_V1_0b.pdf